# Benefits of ARR in a load balanced environment (Azure)?

Tags: iis, load-balancing, cluster, arr

I've built a simple IIS 8 web farm on Azure VMs. The web farm has 3 instances (Windows Server 2012) using shared configuration. The load balancing is handled by the Azure's built-in load balancer.

There's much discussion about IIS Application Request Routing but I wonder what would I gain if I add it to my current web farm? I presume I could use ARR in situations where one of the servers has more resources so that more traffic is directed to that instance? Is there other benefits?

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of ARR as of Nov 2014, is the it provides client affinity to your HTTP requests. As of now, the Azure load balancer / traffic manager does not provide this.